# NSPredicate for regular expression works incorrectly with "№" char

Tags: objective-c, swift, regex

I've found an interesting case while working with regular expressions:

```
NSString *predicateString = @"\\№";
NSString *testString = @"№";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", predicateString];
BOOL matched = [predicate evaluateWithObject: testString]; // NO
```

Escaping non-special character should work in the same way as a simple character according to regexp documentation. However, `predicateString` is probably treated as a special sequence so the result of match is `NO`.

For every other character (including emoji) the same code works correctly.

Interestingly, Swift version

```
let regexpString = "\\№"
let testString = "№"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", regexpString)
let matched = predicate.evaluate(with: testString)
```

crashes on last line with `fatal error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).`

Using the same input data with `NSRegularExpression` for match checking works as expected. I've tried the same things with loading strings from local resources to exclude unnecessary escaping in code, as well as using Unicode character for `№`, but everything is the same.

What is the reason of such a strange behaviour and is there any documentation on it?

Comment: This seems like a Swift bug. I'd suggest raising it as such on [bugs.swift.org](https://bugs.swift.org).

Comment: Note that you can use `NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for:)` to escape only the necessary characters in a string.

Comment: @MartinR ```escapedPattern``` adds another backslash, so the result pattern is ```\\№``` instead of ```\№```. I need some backward action - treat current backslash as a special character for ```\№``` to collapse into simple ```№```

Comment: I can't repro any crash with Swift 5.1. `"№".range(of: #"\№"#, options: .regularExpression) != nil` returns `true`

Comment: [Objective-C code](https://ideone.com/mmCHEQ) also works, output is `true`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ```range(of:``` is working good, it has the same result as ```NSRegularExpression```. Can you please check my code snippet in playground? Regarding objc code - ok, now this is very mysterious, I see the same result (NO) in two different Xcode versions (11.3.1 and 11.6), not sure why the result differs from online compiler, but I'm 100% sure it's reproducible. I'm running it in simple view app in simulator

Comment: `\№`  is normalized to `\No`. On macOS 10.13 I get an exception.